# Is there a way to express a value as stars in bootstrap/razor?

Tags: asp.net-core, model-view-controller, razor, bootstrap-4, model

I am pulling in a score value out of 10 from a model (@Model.score) in a cshtml page, but instead of the score, I would like it to come up as a star rating. It is an int. Any methods I find you can only set how many stars are checked or unchecked manually. I'd like to pass on the value from the model and have it represented as a star rating.

Comment: Can you share your what you do now,and what star rating you are using?